# How to write symbol in csv file?

Tags: python-2.7, csv

I am trying to write username and symbol into my csv file from python code,but whenever my loop come to that line it skip that record and write next record in the file.Thank you in advance. Please help me in writing symbol into csv file

For example:
    I want to write(Simeon Miller ✪)this name into name column.

Comment: Can you please share your code where it's happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python doesn't magically skip records unless you explicitly code that.  Assuming the data is of type `unicode` you have to encode it before writing it to the file.  UTF-8 is a safe bet because that encoding can encode all possible characters in `unicode` strings.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8
import csv


def main():
    data = [[u'Simeon Miller ✪', 42], [u'Roger Rabbit', 4711]]
    with open('test.csv', 'wb') as csv_file:
        writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
        for name, number in data:
            writer.writerow([name.encode('utf-8'), str(number)])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```